# Where can I find a list of all GHC extensions

Tags: haskell, ghc

I wanted to use `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` but I forgot how it's called. This kind of thing isn't hoogle-able, and also it takes some time finding using google*.

Is there somewhere a list of GHC extensions named as they are in the `LANGUAGE` pragma?

* My googling search journey:

- Google
- Haskell at wikipedia
- GHC at wikipedia
- [GHC language features](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/ghc-language-features.html)
- [Overload string literals](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#overloaded-strings)
- `OverloadedStrings`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The ["Language options"](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html#id598783) section of [the flag reference page](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html) has a list that's much more easily browseable than the language features page.

Once you're there a `Ctrl-F` search for "overloaded" takes you right to what you want.

Comment: Yep, and the ghc man page is also good.  Always makes me feel sorry for people on manless platforms.

Comment: The most recent docs for language extensions is https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts.html, and the most recent GHC flags docs is https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html

Answer (score 29):

ghci's tab-completion knows. Type `:set -X` at a ghci prompt, then hit Tab, and you'll get a full list. Or `:set -XFoo` then Tab will get you a list of all extensions beginning with `Foo`.

Comment: Your answer is extra-useful because it also introduced me to `:set -X`!

Answer (score 22):

```
$ ghc --supported-languages
```

(from [GHC docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/pragmas.html))

Comment: `ghc --supported-languages | sort | sed -e "s/^\(.*\)$/{-# LANGUAGE \1 #-}/" | fzf | xclip`

Answer (score 3):

ghc-mod for Emacs found here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-mod, includes completion for language extensions. If you are an Emacs user, I suggest you to try it.

Comment: Also with Spacemacs `SPC I s` starts ya-snippet with helm which is very handy to insert language extension.

Answer (score 3):

When using [Leksah](http://www.leksah.org/) IDE, selecting Package menu, then Edit Package menu item, then Extension tab also gives you a checkable list.

Answer (score 2):

My dumb hacky way of doing such things:

```
$ man ghc | grep String
       -XExtendedDefaultRules   -XNoExtendedDefaultRules   -XOverloadedStrings
       -XNoOverloadedStrings  -XGADTs -XNoGADTs   -XGADTSyntax  -XNoGADTSyntax
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Cabal package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal) provides a [Language.Haskell.Extension module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-2.0.1.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Extension.html) which exports a [KnownExtension type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-2.0.1.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Extension.html#t:KnownExtension) whose each constructor is an extension.

The documentation of each constructor briefly describes the extension and provides a link to the GHC user guide.